# Create three columns based on 1 single column

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, date-arithmetic, postgresql-9.6

**I want to compare results from this year with last years results and then compare last year results with two years ago results.**

The values for last_year (2019) are replicated to match dates of 2020 so that I can do the comparison.
I am trying to build something like this:

```
date    this_year   last_year   2_year_ago
Jan-18                              9
feb-18                              18
mar-18                              22
Apr-18                              17
may-18                              29
jun-18                              41
jul-18                              32
Aug-18                              19
sep-18                              28
oct-18                              25
nov-18                              20
Dec-18                              29
Jan-19                  28          9
feb-19                  59          18
mar-19                  56          22
Apr-19                  45          17
may-19                  45          29
jun-19                  48          41
jul-19                  76          32
Aug-19                  46          19
sep-19                  86          28
oct-19                  107         25
nov-19                  125         20
Dec-19                  179         29
Jan-20  223             28  
feb-20  235             59  
mar-20  224             56  
Apr-20  86              45  
may-20  131             45  
jun-20  107             48  
jul-20  137             76  
Aug-20  53              46  
sep-20  115             86  
oct-20  137             107 
nov-20  130             125 
Dec-20  51              179
```

Postgresql version: `PostgreSQL 9.6.1`

So far  I have created this code:

```
select load_date1, load_date2, this_year, last_year
from (
        select load_date as load_date1, series_value as this_year,
                    extract(month from load_date)::int as month_1
        from table_values
        where load_date >=  (current_date - 365) 
                  and load_date <= current_date
    ) as t1 
    inner join 
    (
        select load_date as load_date2, series_value as last_year,
                extract(month from load_date)::int as month_2
        from table_values
        where load_date >=  (current_date - 730) 
                  and load_date <= current_date -365
    ) as t2 
    on t1.month_1 = t2.month_2
```

I don't know to how continue or how make the query the right way.

The table has the following information:

load_date, series_value

Comment: WHy you don't have value in the column `2_year_ago` for `Jan-20`?

Comment: With the information I create a graph that compares the values doing it year over year.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions. Assuming one `load_date` per month, at the first day of the month:

```
select *
from (
    select load_date, series_values as this_year,
        sum(series_values) over(order by load_date range between interval '1 year' preceding and '1 year' preceding) as last_year,
        sum(series_values) over(order by load_date range between interval '2 year' preceding and '2 year' preceding) as last_last_year
    from table_values
) t
where load_date >= current_date - interval '1 year' and load_date < current_date
```

Or, if you have more than one value per month, and you want to sum them:

```
select *
from (
    select date_trunc('month', load_date) as load_month, sum(series_values) as this_year,
        sum(sum(series_values)) over(order by date_trunc('month', load_date) range between interval '1 year' preceding and '1 year' preceding) as last_year,
        sum(sum(series_values)) over(order by date_trunc('month', load_date) range between interval '2 year' preceding and '2 year' preceding) as last_last_year
    from table_values
    group by date_trunc('month', load_date)
) t
where load_month >= date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1 year' and load_month < date_trunc('month', current_date)
```

Comment: Thanks for being so quickly responding. I am trying all your examples but postgresql keeps prompting `  ERROR: RANGE PRECEDING is only supported with UNBOUNDED
`

Comment: @jalazbe: which version of Postgres are you running?

Comment: I am using a portable version: `PostgreSQL 9.6.1`

Comment: @jalazbe: that's a really old version - so there is poor support for `range` window frames. Any plans of upgrading to a newer version (the latest is version 13...)?

Comment: I am afraid is company policy. I'd love to update it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem that conditional aggregation solves.

If you have one load per month, then conditional aggregation should do what you want:

```
select extract(month from load_date) as month,
       max(series_value) filter (where extract(year from load_date) = extract(year from now())) as this_year,
       max(series_value) filter (where extract(year from load_date) = extract(year from now()) - 1) as prev_year,
       max(series_value) filter (where extract(year from load_date) = extract(year from now()) - 2) as year_before_that
from table_values
group by extract(month from load_date)
order by max(load_date);
```

This returns 12 rows, one for each month.  I don't see a need for the rows for the additional years.  All the data you need is in one row.